# Usage of C definition

Tags: c

I have a question about the definition in c code as bellow.

```
#define DESC(x) 1

#if DESC("abc cdef")
.... some implementation or declaration
#endif
```

What exactly does the macro **DESC("abc cdef")** mean?
Does it stand for a sub module? It this is true, where can I refer to the information about it?

Thank you for go through this question.

Comment: Not much different that `#define TRUE 1`, except here you can simply pass a parameter and the expression will evaluate as `1` just the same. You could pass `DESC ("alligators")` and the answer is still `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DESC(x)` is a function-like preprocessor macro.  In your case, it ignores its input and always replaces it with an integer literal `1`.

I don't know for certain *why* it's being used this way, but I suspect the author wanted:

1. To add descriptions to sections of code.
2. To clearly delimit what sections those descriptions apply to (via `#if` ... `#endif`).

(Most people would use comments for #1, but with just comments sometimes #2 is unclear.)

Comment: `DESC` could possibly be a "descending order" flag. Still, the argument would be extraneous.

Comment: @jackw11111 "Desc" is a fairly common abbreviation for "Description", which seems far more likely given the string argument.

Comment: Thanks you guys' reply, I think "To add description to sections of code" could be most common idea. Based on this comment, I am wondering that could I find any reference from the map file after compiler.

Comment: @CM Lin Unless there's some separate tool that runs over the code, no, those strings won't appear anywhere.  The preprocessor will strip them out before the compiler even sees them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [function-like macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html), which takes in `x` as a parameter and returns `1`.